# issue unit testisng a RestController post request with mockmvc. It performs the request correctly when debug but why does mock response comes empty?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, mockmvc

I am kind of new to testing and am currently having an issue **unit testing a Spring RestController** with **MockMvc**. The problem shows itself when I perform a post request to **Add a new User** with a requestBody and I get the http status that the request was performed successfully, but once I get the response converted to a String from MvcResult, it comes an empty String.

I debugged the test and checked that the request was performed, and the request body was taken successfully and has passed all validations, so following this logic my thoughts are that the problem lies with Mockito but I don't quite understand why. Can someone give me a pointer to what I am doing incorrectly?

This my Entity User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator= "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name="UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private String id;

  @NotBlank(message = ResponseMessage.ERROR_INVALID_FIRST_NAME_INPUT)
  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @NotBlank(message = ResponseMessage.ERROR_INVALID_LAST_NAME_INPUT)
  @Column(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;

  @NotBlank(message = ResponseMessage.ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL_INPUT)
  @Email(message = ResponseMessage.ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL_INPUT)
  @Column(name = "email")
  private String email;

  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  @NotBlank(message = ResponseMessage.ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD_INPUT)
  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name = "phone_number")
  private String phoneNumber;

  @Column(name = "address")
  private String address;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @Column(name = "registered_on")
  private Date registeredDate;
  // Constructors and setters and getters down here
}
```

This is the rest controller:

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @PostMapping("/add")
  public Response<Object> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    return this.userService.addUser(user);

  // other methods down here
  }

}
```

And this is my rest controller test:

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @MockBean
  private UserService userService;

  private List<User> users;

  void populateUsers() {
    users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User("test","test","test@test.com","test"));
    users.add(new User("test1","test1","test1@test.com","test1"));
    users.add(new User("test2","test2","test2@test.com","test2"));
  }

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    populateUsers();
  }

  @AfterEach
  void clear() {
    users.clear();
  }
     // other tests here. that actually work
 
  @Test
  void addUser() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    Response<Object> expected = new Response<>(200, ResponseMessage.SUCCESS_SAVED_USER);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    User user = new User("Added","User","a@user.com","itWorks");
    String content = "{" +
            "\"firstName\":\"Added\"," +
            "\"lastName\":\"User\"," +
            "\"email\":\"a@user.com\"," +
            "\"password\":\"itWorks\"" +
            "}";
   Mockito.when(userService.addUser(user)).thenReturn(expected);

    // Act
    String actual = mvc
            .perform(TestHttpRequestBuilderHelper.httpPostRequestBuilder("/user/add", content))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse()
            .getContentAsString();

    // Assert
    assertEquals(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expected), actual);
  }
  
}
```

I used another helper class in building the MockMvcRequestBulders called TestHttpRequestBuilderHelper:

```
public class TestHttpRequestBuilderHelper {

  private static HttpHeaders generateHttpHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    httpHeaders.add("Accept","application/json");
    return httpHeaders;
  }
   // other overloaded methods here
 
  public static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder httpPostRequestBuilder(String url, String content) {
    return MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(url).headers(generateHttpHeaders()).content(content);
  }

}
```

This is the log output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /user/add
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"81"]
             Body = {"firstName":"Added","lastName":"User","email":"a@user.com","password":"itWorks"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.bibliotek.library.user.UserController
           Method = com.bibliotek.library.user.UserController#addUser(User)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :{"httpCode":200,"message":"User was added successfully"}
Actual   :
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)
    at com.bibliotek.library.user.UserControllerTest.addUser(UserControllerTest.java:116)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


2020-12-07 11:33:43.380  INFO 16288 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

So to be successful it must be like this:

```
exptected: {"httpCode":200,"message":"User was added successfully"} 
actual : {"httpCode":200,"message":"User was added successfully"}
```

but in my case its returning :

```
expected: {"httpCode":200,"message":"User was added successfully"}
actual: ""
```

Comment: on this line `assertEquals(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expected), actual);` print out the two different strings. What is the difference between them?

Comment: I updated it above. You can see it at the end.

Comment: Ah yes I see. You try to compare the complete response object to the content of the actual response object.